# How to define MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

This code works correct:

```
func setInfoCenterCredentials(_ artist: String, _ title: String, _ image: UIImage) {
    let mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()        
    let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
    mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: title,
                           MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: artist,
                           MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt]
}
```

But Xcode complains on : `let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)`,

> 'init(image:)' was deprecated in iOS 10.0

I have tried to just put the `image` as `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: image`, but that results in a crash.

How do I set it correctly for iOS 10.0? Help is very appreciated.

Edit: Yes. I have found the section in the documentation:

```
init(boundsSize: CGSize, requestHandler: @escaping (CGSize) -> UIImage)
```

But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: undeleted my question even tho i have downvotes... yes, I have found this before, but I don't know how to handle this. sorry for my stupid question and my lack in knowledge...

Comment: Now that you've changed the way you're asking the question, it's a pretty good question so I've retracted my downvote. How _do_ you use it? I'll show you, hang on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what is this initializer asking for? It wants a size (fair enough) and it wants a *function* that provides the image given the size.

So you *could* implement it naively like this:

```
let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize:mySize) { sz in
    return image
}
```

That, with the necessary blanks filled in, should get you past the compiler (let me know if it doesn't; I haven't tested it). However, it's not a very good implementation! What you *should* do in the function is size your image down to the size requested in the incoming parameter (`sz` in my code). I think I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...!

Comment: what I don't get about that is, that before by `let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)`, I'm `setting` an image, the image called `image`. with the new way i'm `returning` an image. but what image? and how do i put `my` `UIImage` as `albumArt`

Comment: In my code, you're still setting it as the image called `image`. And you're still setting it as `albumArt`. I don't understand the question.

Comment: oh. you're right... I've just tried it. guess I was reading the code wrong... i thought that return always returns the `result` of the function... I did not understand it, because from my point of view, I was not giving the `function` my `image` as parameter... thank you very much for your help

Comment: Functions are closures. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_closures